# Mean by properties in array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typescript, lodash.js

I have this array of objects:

```
const array = [
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2018', value:10},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2017', value:15},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2016', value:2},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2018', value:20},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2017', value:1},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2016', value:20},
]
```

I want a new array with the mean by year:

```
const result = [
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'', year:'2018', value:15},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'', year:'2017', value:8},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'', year:'2016', value:11},
]
```

This is my code:

```
const yearsTemp = Array.from(new Set(dataset.map((datum: any) => datum.year)).values())
const years = yearsTemp.map(year => year.toString())
const means = years.map(year => {
  const filtered = filter(dataset, { continent: continent, year: year })
  const mean = filtered.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0) / filtered.length
  return {
    continent: dataset[0].continent,
    country: '',
    year: year,
    value: mean,
  }
})
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Is this actually typescript? it doesn't look like valid (vanilla) javascript. And where is `filter` defined?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Yeas, it's Typescript. `filter` is a lodash function (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is labelled TypeScript, I'm going to review it as such. First of all, you aren't using *types*, which defeats the purpose of using **Type**Script. You should define what your objects look like

```
interface Datum { //not sure what to call it
    continent: string,
    country: string,
    year: string,
    value: number
}
```

I'm not a TypeScript expert or anything, but even as a beginner, I'd expect something *at least* like this. With this, we get that the year is apparently a string. Maybe it's not an issue but it's something to note. Before defining the type I just glanced at the object and assumed it was a number.

Which means that your `array` declaration should now look like this

```
const array : Array<Datum> = [
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2018', value:10},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2017', value:15},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2016', value:2},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2018', value:20},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2017', value:1},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2016', value:20},
]
```

and the compiler would know what you are working with providing type safety for future operations.

Now, let's take a look at some other declarations

```
const yearsTemp : Array<string> = Array.from(new Set(dataset.map((datum: Datum) => datum.year)).values())
```

Assuming `dataset` has a content similar to `array` in the beginning, the types we annotate are `Datum` for each variable. This means that we are mapping each `year` value and get an array of string. However, calling `.values()` on the `Set` is superfluous - `Array.from()` works fine with just being passed a `Set`. So, you can drop that.

But what about the next line

```
const years: Array<string> = yearsTemp.map(year => year.toString())
```

So, we take an array of strings and produce an array of strings. That's *fine* normally, but to do that you call `.toString()` on each value. That's a pointless operation `"some value".toString()` is the same thing. It's also *dangerous*, as `null.toString()` would cause an error. For future reference, a way that wouldn't throw a null pointer exception is to pass the value through the `String` constructor function but *don't* use the keyword `new`.

```js
let numericValue = 42;

let stringValue = String(numericValue);

console.log("typeof stringValue", typeof stringValue);
console.log('stringValue === "42"', stringValue === "42");

//this creates a new object string, not a string primitive
let dontDoThis = new String(numericValue);

console.log("typeof dontDoThis", typeof dontDoThis);
console.log('dontDoThis === "42"', dontDoThis === "42"); //not the same type
console.log('dontDoThis === new String("42")', dontDoThis === new String("42")); //not the same object
```

Passing the value `null` or `undefined` through `String` will not cause an error but it will produce the string `"null"` or `"undefined"` respectively. You can filter those out, if you don't want them

```js
let objectsWithNumericValues = [{year: 2018}, {year: 2019}, {year: 2019}, {year: 2020}, {year: null}];

let extractedYears = objectsWithNumericValues.map(obj => obj.year);
let resultWithNull = Array.from(new Set(extractedYears))
  .map(String); //<-- convert to string

let resultWithoutNull = Array.from(new Set(extractedYears))
  .filter(Boolean) //<-- filter anything falsey
  .map(String);
  
console.log(resultWithNull);
console.log(resultWithoutNull);
```

On a separate note, the above code shows how you can avoid temporary variables by chaining operations. It saves some typing and it's clearer by not having clutter like throw-away variable names. But it also depends on the coding style.

Anyway, back on the topic of getting the years and turning them into strings - just drop the line that does `toString` and rename `const yearsTemp` to `const years`

As for the rest it seems OK, as long as you add the types. It's not clear where the `continent` variable is coming from when you call `filter(dataset, { continent: continent, year: year })` but I'd assume you have that in context. The other strange this is `dataset[0].continent`. I'm not sure if that's correct or not, as it would take the same `continent` for each new produced value and it's not necessarily going to be the correct one unless `dataset[0].continent === continent`. But that might be a typo when transcribing the code here. Perhaps the same is true for `country: ''`

The only change I'd make is separate the functionality instead of put all the processing into `.map()`. The chaining of array operation makes the separation of intentions clearer and if you need to extract functionality, it's cleaner.

```
years
    .map(year => filter(dataset, { continent: continent, year: year }))
    .map(filtered => {
        const mean = filtered.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0) / filtered.length
        return {
            continent: dataset[0].continent,
            country: '',
            year: year,
            value: mean
        }
    })
```

this way if you decide that either or both functionalities are reusable, you can separate them and your logic turns into

```
years
    .map(getResultsWithTheSameYear)
    .map(calculateMean)
```

and you can use these functions elsewhere. Perhaps you will have some other functionality where you do

```
countries
    .map(getResultsWithSameCountry)
    .map(calculateMean)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Review points

This code makes good use of the `const` keyword for values that are not re-assigned. That is refreshing to see.

Is the empty `country` property necessary?

### Addressing your question

> Is there a better way

I’d question what “better” in this case means to you- shorter, simpler, more performant?

Because you mentioned you are using lodash, the [`_.meanBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#meanBy) method could be used, along with `_.map()`.

One way would be to group items by year and continent by concatenating those values.

```js
const array = [
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2018', value:10},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2017', value:15},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2016', value:2},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2018', value:20},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2017', value:1},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2016', value:20},
];
const groupedItems = _.groupBy(array, record => record.continent + '_' +  record.year);
const means = _.map(groupedItems, (group, key) => {
  return {
    continent: group[0].continent,
    country: '',
    year: group[0].year,
    value: _.meanBy(group, 'value')
  };
});

console.log('output: ', means);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The `key` property could also be used to fetch the values for the *continent* and *year* of each group - perhaps using [array destructuringSection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and .

```js
const array = [
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2018', value:10},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2017', value:15},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Algeria', year:'2016', value:2},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2018', value:20},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2017', value:1},
  {continent: 'Africa', country:'Egypt', year:'2016', value:20},
];
const groupedItems = _.groupBy(array, record => record.continent + '_' + record.year);
const means = _.map(groupedItems, (group, key) => {
  [continent, year] = key.split('_');
  return {
    continent,
    country: '',
    year,
    value: _.meanBy(group, 'value')
  };
});

console.log('output: ', means);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```